# Distinct from one table, value from another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not sure of the correct way to ask this: I want to select a distinct value from one table and get the value from another table....

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT County_ID FROM Customers ORDER BY County_ID ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql1 ))
{
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT County_Value FROM Counties") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql2 ))
        {
            echo "Listed Counties : ".$row2['County_Value']." - id : ".$row1['County_ID']."<br>";
        }
}
```

But doing it this way I get ORDER BY County id, what is the correct way to do this and a list in ASC for the values? thanks.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT County_ID, County_Value FROM Customers, Counties WHERE Counties.County_ID=Customer.County_ID ORDER BY County_Value ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

PS: I should say that I want to get get a list listed counties from the customers table, but they are stored as id from the counties tables, so I want only distinct countie_values ASC

Comment: Please extend your explanation 'But doing it this way I get ORDER BY County id, what is the correct way to do this and a list in ASC for the values?'. I find it rather unclear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:-

```
SELECT CustomersSub.County_ID, County_Value 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT County_ID FROM Customers) CustomersSub
INNER JOIN Counties 
ON Counties.County_ID = CustomersSub.County_ID 
ORDER BY County_Value ASC
```

Edit -- Or to use an aggregate function and count the customers in each county:-

```
SELECT Counties.County_ID, County_Value, COUNT(Customers.County_ID) AS CustCountyCount
FROM Counties 
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Counties.County_ID = Customers.County_ID 
GROUP BY Counties.County_ID, County_Value
ORDER BY County_Value ASC
```